# How to fix magento 2 error while installing one module

Tags: php, magento2.2

I am have my magento 2 website and I want to install one module using below command

```
composer require eway/eway-rapid-magento2 3.0.1
```

but I am getting following error

```
magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore platform requirements (php & ext- packages).

```
composer require eway/eway-rapid-magento2 3.0.1 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated already,  php version is not correct for this module version, so either update php version or update the module version, which one is satisfying by the php version.